# Nextjs/Reactjs add span inside link tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Want to make breadcrumb based on microdata and I'm using nextjs with reactjs I did:

```
<li itemProp="itemListElement" itemScope itemType="https://schema.org/ListItem">
    <Link href={'/index'} itemProp="item">
       <span itemProp="name">
         home
       </span>
    </Link>
<meta itemProp="position" content="1"/>
</li>
```

But output is:

```
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
  <span itemprop="name">
home
</span>
  <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
</li>
```

But when I click it going to homepage, but looks like it works with js not href. but if I remove span tag, and put like this:

```
<li itemProp="itemListElement" itemScope itemType="https://schema.org/ListItem">
    <Link href={'/index'} itemProp="item">
home
    </Link>
    <meta itemProp="position" content="1"/>
</li>
```

Output:

```
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/ListItem">
  <a href="/index">home</a>
  <meta itemprop="position" content="1">
</li>
```

Why can not use span inside Link tag?

[Google Breadcrumb structure](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/breadcrumb#microdata_1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `<a>` tag inside the Next.js `Link` Component if the `child` is not a `string`. The `<a>` tag is automatically added if the child is a string

so your code should look like this:

```
<li itemProp="itemListElement" itemScope itemType="https://schema.org/ListItem">
    <Link href={'/index'} itemProp="item">
      <a>
       <span itemProp="name">
         home
       </span>
      </a>
    </Link>
<meta itemProp="position" content="1"/>
</li>
```

---

Explanation of why we need a `<a>` is here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/client/link.tsx

Answer (score 0):

SEO best practice is to use an `anchor` tag whenever you have a link. As you deduced correctly, `Link` is just a wrapper component and it does some magic using JS. So you can technically create a `link` with `span` too.

[`passHref`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link) forces `href` to be passed to the immediate child. If you use the `passHref` property like below, the `href` tag will be added to the `span`. :

```
<Link href={'/index'} itemProp="item" passHref>
       <span itemProp="name">
         home
       </span>
    </Link>
```

But this is not good for your SEO. That is why Nextjs docs suggest using an anchor tag.

Now you can wrap `a` inside `span` and vice-versa. Both are perfectly valid, but you would want your `href` to be on your `anchor` tag. And for that you should be using the below code as suggested in another solution:

```
<Link href={'/index'} itemProp="item">
       <a>
       <span itemProp="name">
         home
       </span>
       </a>
</Link>
```